# SQL testing for data in column using LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a query I am writing to test for permission access. One of the columns I have to look through is in the format of `ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL` and I need to see if there is a value that exists in that column.

The problem is, there are multiple things I need to test for which is causing my query to throw an error due to the subquery returning multiple values.

```
-- Default permission
DECLARE @hasAccess BIT = 0;

-- Define our temp data
DECLARE @managers AS TABLE(personnelID VARCHAR(10))

-- Insert our data for the manager test logic
INSERT INTO @managers( personnelID ) VALUES ( 'ABC' )
INSERT INTO @managers( personnelID ) VALUES ( 'XYZ' )


SELECT * 
FROM Employees AS e
WHERE e.QID = @QID
    AND e.PersonnelIDList LIKE '%' + (SELECT personnelID FROM @managers)  + '%'
```

How can I go about testing to see if any one of the values in `@managers` exists in the column value (example column value: `ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL`) exists in the records.

Comment: You need to treat your table variable like any other table. In this case you want to use an inner join or exists.

Comment: Column that contains more than one value is a bad design.

Comment: I agree and understand about the design, limited to what I can work with here on this legacy tool.

Comment: Ah, the dreaded delimited text problem. Your best solution here is to fix that broken schema, but I understand it may not be in your power.

Comment: Will your delimited value always have 4 elements? You _may_ be able to use `parsename()` to get at those values. I think the `LIKE` method may be best.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing lists as strings.  This is just a bad idea.  There should be a separate table instead.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In this case, you can use an `exists` subquery:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM Employees e
WHERE e.QID = @QID AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @managers m
              WHERE '|' + e.PersonnelIDList + '|' LIKE '%|' +personnelID  + '|%'
             );
```

Comment: `LIKE '%|' + foo + '|%'` will miss leading and trailing elements if they don't have a `|` before or after.

Comment: @Shawn . . . Good point.  I had missed the other half of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

In like clause, you're only allowed to have the subquery return a single result.
Join to your @managers table and use the like within the join clause.

```
-- Default permission
DECLARE @hasAccess BIT = 0;

-- Define our temp data
DECLARE @managers AS TABLE(personnelID VARCHAR(10))

-- Insert our data for the manager test logic
INSERT INTO @managers( personnelID ) VALUES ( 'ABC' )
INSERT INTO @managers( personnelID ) VALUES ( 'XYZ' )



SELECT 
    e.* 
FROM 
    Employees AS e
    inner join  @managers as m
            on  e.PersonnelIDList LIKE '%' + m.personnelID  + '%'
WHERE 
    e.QID = @QID
```

---